# Eclipse Run a project error - java hotspot(TM) 64-bit server VM -1.7.0_09 <> 1.5.0

Tags: java, java-7, eclipse-indigo, java-6

I ran a project, an opensource project called Adempiere. It is an Opensource ERP System and am interested in using this ERP. I got the source, downloaded it with SVN in eclipse Indigo.

I ran the project and an error occured saying **java hotspot(TM) 64-bit server VM -1.7.0_09 <> 1.5.0** what is wrong with this? Why did this error occur? I have installed bothh 1.6 and 7 JDK in my System in 64 bit.

Any adempierians out there? Their forums has not been very friendly lately.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be it requires Java 5 (1.5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install jdk 5 and then

Window -> preferences -> Installed JREs

And then go back to your project

Project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> libraries

remove the 1.7 system libaries, and: add library... -> JRE System LIbrary -> Alternate JRE -> The JRE you want. It must be 1.5 in this case.